# How to use external library in a LLVM pass

Tags: c++, boost, llvm

I want to use boost graph library in one of the LLVM passes I am working on. Boost graph library is header only. So usually I can use it as `-I<path to boost source>`. My question is how to use it inside LLVM source tree (inside `lib/Transforms/MyPass`).

I tried the following.

First I tired adding include directory to my pass's CMakeLists.txt like so,
`target_include_directories(LLVMMyPass "<path to boost headers>")`
Next I tried to change the CPP_FLAGS,
`set(CPP_FLAGS "${CPP_FLAGS} -I<path to boost headers> ")`

Both didn't work. I keep getting the error.

`fatal error: boost/graph/graph_traits.hpp: No such file or directory`
 `#include "boost/graph/graph_traits.hpp"`

Update : I tried using `-DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS=-I<path to boost>` in cmake command. That also did not help.

Answer (score 0):

system-wide installation of boost solved the problem

`sudo apt-get install libboost-all-dev`